# Creating dynamic graphs with MVC and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Dependencies:**

Even though for my sample I'm working on randomly generated data, ideally, there is `C#` code that is running a device/Windows Service that will continually spit out data which will be grabbed by the controller. So `MVC` is required. I will also need to use ajax so that the graph is "live" rather than refreshing every time new data is put in.

**Problem:**

Since `MVC` is server-side and `Javascript` is local, I will get null values when starting the site since a lot of the values need to be generated by the `controller` and is then used in `Javascript` to generate a graph. Another problem is that the data from the controller does not "send" to the `Javascript`.

The `function GetLatestFields()` is where I was thinking of having the link between controller and `Javascript`. Right now it is just grabbing what's in the text field and doing the math from there.

**Javascript:**

```
$("#form").on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/graph/generateData',    //<-- manipulate the form data
        type: 'POST',
        success: GetLatestFields()     //<-- send the manipulated data to here
    });
});

// Index Counter
var newDataValueIndex = 0;

const chart = document.getElementById("lineChartGraph");

// Generate Empty Graph
var currentData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Fixed Slope",
            fill: false,  
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [],
        }
    ]
};

function UpdateChart(startValue, stepValue) {
    lineChartObject.data.datasets[0].data[newDataValueIndex] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    lineChartObject.data.labels[newDataValueIndex] = startValue;
    newDataValueIndex += 1;
    startValue += stepValue;
    lineChartObject.update();
}

var customOption = {
    showLines: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Step (mm)'
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Absorbance'
            }
        }]
    }
};

var lineChartObject = Chart.Line(chart, {
    data: currentData,
    options: customOption
});

// ***** This is where I would like to grab data from the controller *****
// Grab most updated values
function GetLatestFields() {
    // I've tried (not at the same time): 
    // @: ViewData["stepValue"].ToString();
    // @(ViewBag.StartValue)
    var startValue = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var stepValue = document.getElementById("step").value;
    UpdateChart(startValue, stepValue);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void generateData(FormCollection collection)
{
    // I've tried ViewBag and ViewData which did not work
    int inputNumber = Request.Form["start"];
    inputNumber = inputNumber*10
    ViewBag.StartValue = inputNumber;
    ViewData["stepValue"] = Request.Form["step"];
}
```

Is there a better approach to this using `.Net`?

I was also thinking of sending the manipulated data to the view first then `onChange`, the `Javascript` will work with the view. But again, the only way I know how to display back what the controller has generated is ViewBag which is rendered on refresh.

So basically:

Old connection:

> View -> Controller -> Js

New Connection:

> View -> Controller -> View -> Js

Comment: Have you considered ajax polling to get data ?

Comment: @Shyju I'm pretty new to doing and server-to-client so any suggestions I'm open to. I'll look into that.